# Parellel HTTPWebrequest URL

Tags: c#, vb.net, url, httpwebrequest, image

I have an app that loads a list of HTTP URLs pointing to pictures to download using winforms. The asynchronously downloaded pictures are placed inside the imagelist. I've already done it but my method only downloads one picture at a time and goes on until every picture has been downloaded. Is there a way to make webrequest download multiple items in parallel to speed up the process? Even if bandwidth is divided, it should still be faster compared to when the app only downloads one picture at a time. VB or C# coding will do. Thank you very much.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Maybe You can call HTTPWebrequest download for each image in another thread...

Comment: Have a look at `Parallel.ForEach()` and PLINQ.

Comment: My program is actually working fine, however, what I did was to download the specific file stated by each item in the list one by one, so if i have 5 items on the list with 1 mb to download each, the second item needs to wait for the first item to be downloaded and so on...I'm currently using webrequest now...What I prefer is for the program to download multiple items simultaneously...I've tried the HTTPrequest in another thread, it actually works, but I'm pretty sure there's still a better way, more efficient than this, am i right?

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach

https://github.com/dodyg/hobi-hobi/blob/master/HobiHobi.Core/Syndications/SyndicationFetcher.cs

```
  public List<FeedAndSource> DownloadAll(RssSubscription subscription)
    {
        var feeds = var feeds = new SynchronizedCollection<FeedAndSource>();

        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var sub in subscription.Items)
        {
            var r = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var res = Fetch(sub.XmlUri);
                    if (res.IsFound)
                        feeds.Add(new FeedAndSource(sub, res.Item));
                });

            tasks.Add(r);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        return feeds.toList();
    }
```

All you have to care about is Task.Factory.StartNew and Task.WaitAll.

You can find them at

using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

As comment pointed out, List is not thread safe. Use  SynchronizedCollection instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx

Comment: This code is not thread-safe. You can't just access a `List` from multiple threads at the same time like that.